# Installing .Net Framework on a new machine windows 7

Tags: iis, .net, visual-studio

I have a question on best way of installing .Net on a fresh install of Windows 7.

I spoke to a colleague of mine who suggested downloading all the version of .net framework from Microsoft and then installing IIS 7 afterwards. The thing is I am not sure if all this is required.

He wanted me to do the installations in this order

- Install all versions of .net up to version 4 from Microsoft website.
- Install IIS through Windows 7.
- Install SQL Server Management Studio.
- Finally install visual studio 2008 and 2010.

What would everyone else suggest?

Answer (score 2):

Get the Web Platform Installer and install:

- .NET 4
- VS 2010
- MVC 4
- IIS
- SQL Server Management Console (a bit tricky to choose right options in installer)

Answer (score 1):

Does that machine actually *need* every version of .NET? When I set up machines I only install what is *required* and the sequence has never been an issue for me. It doesn't even matter if you have the very latest version of each .NET as they will get updated anyway, assuming you have Windows Update enabled. Talking of which, I ensure new machines are fully up to date with all patches applied before I hand them over to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Install the version(s) of .NET you are targeting. There is no need to install every version.

You can install in any order. If an application has a prerequisite for a given .NET version you will be prompted to install it then.

One caveat to the order of installations is IIS and any .NET framework. If you install any version of .NET after the install of IIS then you will need to register ASP.NET with IIS. You want to invoke the aspnet_regiis.exe utility with the /i argument. The binary can be located in the targeted .NET framework folder. For example, if targeting v4.0 then the binary can be located at %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe for 64-bit and %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe for 32-bit.